# UIBarButtonItem is not Highlighted after setting

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, xcode9

I have declared two UIBarButtonItem, btnEdit and btnSave. initially i'm setting btnEdit in viewDidLoad. if user taps on btnEdit i want to set btnSave as rightBarButtonItem and when tapped on btnSave, set btnEdit 
 as rightBarButtonItem.

it is working fine and i'm able to tap on it but after first tap button is faded/ not in highlighted state. Images Attached.
How do i make it have normal State?

```
var btnEdit : UIBarButtonItem!
var btnSave : UIBarButtonItem!

@objc func btnEditTapped (){
    textFieldViewNote.isEditable = true
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnSave
}


@objc func btnSaveTapped (){
    textFieldViewNote.isEditable = false
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnEdit

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btnSave = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(btnSaveTapped))
    btnEdit = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(btnEditTapped))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnEdit

}
```

[After loading VC - Edit in normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOhKC.png)

[After tapping on edit - Save btn in normal State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VBbp.png)

[Edit faded tapping on save barbutton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbKNV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the fixed code

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var btnEdit : UIBarButtonItem!
    var btnSave : UIBarButtonItem!

    @objc func btnEditTapped (){
        btnSave = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(btnSaveTapped));

      navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnSave

    }


    @objc func btnSaveTapped (){
        btnEdit = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(btnEditTapped));        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnEdit


    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnSave = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(btnSaveTapped))
        btnEdit = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(btnEditTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnEdit

    }
}
```